Formal definition of sufficient statistic
Let $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ and $(\Omega _T,\mathcal{F}_T)$ be measurable spaces. Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a family of probability measures on $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X)$. Let $X:\Omega\to \Omega _X$ and $T:\Omega_X\to \Omega _T$ be measurable functions with respect to $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}_X$ and $\mathcal{F}_X/\mathcal{F}_T$.
According to the book "A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference" written by Li and Babu (see this link), we have the following definition:

A statistic $T=T(X)$ is sufficient for $\mathfrak{M}$ if, for each
$B\in\mathcal{F}_X$, there is a function $\kappa _B:\Omega _X\to
 \mathbb{R}$, measurable $T^{-1}(\mathcal{F}_T)/\mathcal{R}$, such that
for each $P\in\mathfrak{M}$, we have $P(B|T)=\kappa_B$ $P$-a.e..

Suppose that $\mathfrak{M}$ is dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure.
In the proof of Theorem 2.4 of this book (see this link), we know that there's a probability measure $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{F}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(B|T)=\mathbb{P}(B|T)$ $\color{red}{P}$-a.e. for all $P\in\mathfrak{M}$. Besides, $\mathbb{P}$ has the following property: $P\ll \mathbb{P}$ for all $P\in \mathfrak{M}$ and, for any $E\in\mathcal{F}_X$, if $P(E)=0$ for all $P\in\mathfrak{M}$, then $\mathbb{P}(E)=0$.
My question is: does $P(B|T)=\mathbb{P}(B|T)$ $\color{red}{\mathbb{P}}$-a.e. hold for any $P\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_X$? At least, is there a probability measure  $\mathbb{Q}:\mathcal{F}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(B|T)= \mathbb{Q}(B|T)$ $\color{red}{\mathbb{Q}}$-a.e. for any $P\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_X$?

This question is related to the formal definition of a sufficient statistic. Apparently it's common to assume that, for a given sufficient statistic $T$, there's a probability measure  $\mathbb{Q}:\mathcal{F}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(B|T)= \mathbb{Q}(B|T)$ $\color{red}{\mathbb{Q}}$-a.e. for any $P\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_X$. However this assumption doesn't appear to hold in the general case if we use the previous definition of sufficient statistic (which aligns with definition in the paper of Halmos and Savage, as you can see in this link).

The google book link shows "image not available" (at least for me).

@User1865345 To me every link is working. But at least I copied the definition in the question!

Yes. I have fixed the author's surname. The theorem you are talking about is Halmos-Savage Theorem.

@User1865345 : Might it be known as Fisher's factorization criterion rather than as the Halmos–Savage theorem?

Somehow missed your comment, @MichaelHardy. I was talking about the dominant measure equivalent to the family of probability measures -- this follows from Halmos-Savage. Later on, based on that, the characterization of sufficiency as a density in a factorized form is deduced.

I am failing to see any problem.
For a collection of probability measures $\mathfrak M:=\{P_\theta,\theta\in\Theta\},$ the statistic $T$ is sufficient if there exists a version of $\mathbf E_\theta [1\! \! 1_A\mid \sigma(T) ],$ independent of $\theta, $ that is for each $\theta\in\Theta, $ there exists a $\sigma(T) /\mathscr B_\mathbb R$– measurable function $\kappa_A$ which is a version of $P_\theta(A\mid T). $
When working in a dominated model, then $\mathfrak M\equiv \{P_{\theta_1},P_{\theta_2},\ldots\}\equiv P_0:=\sum_n c_n P_{\theta_n}, ~c_n> 0\wedge \sum_n c_n=1.$
The sufficient condition for $T$ to be sufficient is that the RN derivative $\frac{\mathrm dP_\theta}{\mathrm dP_0}$ is $\sigma(T) $ measurable. Why? For it ensures almost surely $P_\theta,$ a version independent of $\theta, $ viz. $\kappa_A=P_0(A\mid T), $ that is $$ P_\theta(A\mid T) =P_0(A\mid T) ~~~~~[P_\theta]~~\forall \theta \in\Theta.$$

@rfloc, why would $\kappa_A$ need to be a regular version in definition of sufficiency? It doesn't need to be a Markov kernel, does it?

We will be needing a regular version only when we are dealing with exhaustive statistic (Blackwell sufficient, which is not same as sufficient; see my answer).

I understood incorrectly what you wrote. I agree with everything you wrote. The problem is that I saw some proofs in the internet which seem to assume that that equality is true for $\mathbb{Q}$-ae. When I wrote the question I was still trying to understand about sufficiency. Now I know how to deal with sufficient statistics even without the existence of a probability $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying that property.

I am not seeing the necessity of such argument but am not refuting any without seeing such (could you cite me any of those proofs/results that use $\mathbb Q$?) The characterization (the last expression) simply follows from the sufficient condition for a aub-sigma-field to be sufficient @rfloc.

What I remember is that this question was made in order to answer this other question. I don’t remember very much what I had in my mind that time because I was able to solve the problems I had without making more assumptions. Anyway, thank you very much!

@rfloc, isn't what you wrote at Maths the same expression of my answer? Let me read that post first. I am not seeing any difference though.

@rfloc, read that. I can confirm that it is indeed the same expression. It seems you were at the right track from the beginning and yet somehow you got confused. Your $\mathbb P_0$ is my $P_0, $ for instance.
